# PhoneGap - only native Google maps directions

Tags: cordova

I have developed an app for iOS and Android and when pressing "directions" it opens in the browser for both iOS and Android but would prefer the directions to open in the native Google maps applicaton, is there any advice on how to do it?

Here is my code;

```
function loadMapDirections() {

try {

    var startingLocation = USER_LAT + "," + USER_LNG;

    var destination = PARK_LAT + "," + PARK_LNG;

    var url = "https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=" + startingLocation

    + "&daddr=" + destination;

    window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: You need custom WebIntent plugin to open native map. May this link help you to write WebIntent plugin http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

To generate route in your application you can use this solution:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/839